# Issue with function and post ID

Tags: wordpress, foreach, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am using the following function/shortcode in order to output an average global rating using ACF :

```
function get_average_rating($post_id) {

   $rating_sum = 0;

   $reviews_of_post = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'avis',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'produit',
            'value' => $post_id,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
) );

if ( empty( $reviews_of_post ) ) {
    return 0;
}

foreach ( $reviews_of_post as $review ) {
    $rating_sum += get_field( 'note_client', 'post_' . $review->ID);
}

return number_format((float)($rating_sum / count( $reviews_of_post )),1, ',', '');
}

add_shortcode( 'note-clients', 'get_average_rating');
```

It always return 0 except when I manually input the post ID like :

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'produit',
        'value' => 1234,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
),
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Declare `global $post;` before your function.

Wordpress uses $post for many of its functions within the loop. 
To avoid any conflicts later you should consider use of `wp_reset_query`

Answer (score 0):

1 . Change key  'key' => 'produit' to  'key' => 'product',

2 .

```
foreach ( $reviews_of_post as $review ) {
    $rating_sum += get_field( 'note_client', 'post_' . $review->ID);
}

**to**

foreach ( $reviews_of_post as $review ) {
 $post_id   = 'post_' . $review->ID ;
 $rating_sum += get_field( 'note_client', $post_id );
 }
```

Confirm ACF key (note_client) is correct

3 . Change this

```
add_shortcode( 'note-clients', 'get_average_rating');
```

**to**

```
add_shortcode( 'average_rating', 'get_average_rating');
```

Comment: Not solving... Actually my custom field (relationship) is called 'produit' so don't need to change the name. 'note_client' is correct also

Answer (score -1):

Please try with your post static id:

```
$post_id = 9; //add here your static post id
   $reviews_of_post = get_posts( array(
       'post_type' => 'avis',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'produit',
               'value' => $post_id,
               'compare' => '=',
           ),
       ),
   ) );
```

Comment: It's working when static as mentionned before. But I need it to be dynamic...

Comment: Please replace static id with get_the_ID(); and let me know the result after this.

Comment: Working ! I also managed to make it work with : global $post; $post_id = $post->ID;
What is the best way ?